# How can I put interface in a seperate file?

Tags: java, class, interface

I am stuck with this error. I want to put my interface and class in separate files. But the compiler is throwing an error. Any suggestion will be appreciated

I have create an interface and class

**..test\t1.java**

```
package test;

 interface t1
{
    public void sayHello();
}
```

**..\test\HelloWorld.java**

```
package test;

public class HelloWorld implements t1
{
    public void sayHello()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        HelloWorld h=new HelloWorld();
        h.sayHello();
    }
}
```

I tried to compile it but the compiler is throwing an error

```
test>javac HelloWorld.java
HelloWorld.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
public class HelloWorld implements t1
                                   ^
  symbol: class t1
1 error
```

Comment: `javac HelloWorld.java t1.java`

Comment: It compiled without any error. But How to run it? @Slaw When I tried java HelloWorld interpreter says `E:\user\java\test>java  HelloWorld
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld`

Comment: @Slaw if I try `E:\user\java\test>java -cp . HelloWorld
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
`

Comment: You need to give the fully qualified class name; i.e `cd E:\user\java` then `java -cp . test.HelloWorld`.

Comment: @StephenC it worked. You answer this question. I will accept it. Although slaw suggestion helped me in compilation.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the package statements. But I'm glad you managed to get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For compilation**

I didn't include the complete path

```
javac -classpath e:\user\java; HelloWorld.java
```

**Run**

I didn't include the valid package name with class name for execution.

```
    E:\user\java\test>java -classpath e:\user\java\; test.HelloWorld
Hello World
```